# What is the use of div tags in template property - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

What does the following line do

```
template: '<div ui-view class="fade-in-down"></div>'
```

I have used templateUrl attribute but what does template attribute do?

```
.state('app.page', {
            url: '/page',
            template: '<div ui-view class="fade-in-down"></div>'
        })     
.state('app.page.profile', {
            url: '/profile',
            templateUrl: 'tpl/page_profile.html'
        })
```

Comment: template: can contain the markup you have in tpl/page_profile.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does the same thing as templateUrl, except that instead to do an AJAX request to a URL to load the template, it gets it directly from the value of the `template` attribute.

Comment: thank you very much @JB Nizet, i'm just started learning and experimenting it